# Open Source implementation of oriented Basic Image Features for Computer Vision?

Tags: computer-vision

Does anyone know if there is an open source implementation of oriented Basic Image Features (oBIF)? There's talk about it at http://www.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/m.lillholm/or.html and http://blog.kaggle.com/2011/05/04/andrew-newell-and-lewis-griffin-on-winning-the-icdar-2011-competition/. I looked through OpenCV some, but I didn't see anything that looked like this. But maybe I just don't understand all the terminology?

If not, I'd like to try to understand how hard it would be to implement. But I'm new to machine vision, and I'm having trouble understanding the image-specific jargon at the links above ('saddle-like', '2nd order gaussian filter bank', etc - I do know what a Gaussian is -just not a 2nd order filter bank of Gaussian's). What's a good reference for learning these machine vision concepts?

Full disclosure: I would like to know how to use them to compete in this years Kaggle competition (http://www.kaggle.com/c/awic2012) for Arabic Handwriting Recognition. I have more of a Machine Learning background, but I'm interested in using the features that won last years competition.